# Можно ли в ChartJS разместить два bar'a в одном "стлобике"?

Tags: javascript, chart.js

Думаю, проще будет привести пример. Есть вот такой график:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
В каждом дне недели есть "bar". Мне необходимо сделать вот так:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Чтобы в одном дне недели было 2, 3 и т.д. bar'ов.

Возможно ли это?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

При добавлении второго dataset'a именно так, как описано выше и произойдет.

```
var barData = {
    labels: ['Italy', 'UK', 'USA', 'Germany', 'France', 'Japan'],
    datasets: [
        {
            label: '2010 customers #',
            fillColor: '#382765',
            data: [2500, 1902, 1041, 610, 1245, 952]
        },
        {
            label: '2014 customers #',
            fillColor: '#7BC225',
            data: [3104, 1689, 1318, 589, 1199, 1436]
        }
    ]
};

var context = document.getElementById('clients').getContext('2d');
var clientsChart = new Chart(context).Bar(barData);
```

[jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/6bjy9nxh/?utm_source=website&utm_medium=embed&utm_campaign=6bjy9nxh)